# Scroll wheel not working during selection

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, scrolling

In Excel 2010, my scroll wheel doesn't scroll on roll while I'm holding the left mouse button to make a selection. Without the left mouse button, it works. Is it a bug or just me, any remedies?

To me, holding the pointer near the screen edge is a very slow alternative to scroll. I know I can also use two clicks + the Shift key, but it's not as quick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not just you, for what it's worth.

Remember that the farther down below the screen edge you drag your cursor, the faster it scrolls. I was able to traverse 1000 rows in 3 seconds with this method, so it's not "slow", but rather uncontrolled.

Comment: Thanks Christian. You're right, actually I mean the same thing. With its hard to control behaviour, the whole action takes longer for short scroll distances. When working with the wheel, it's nearly instant with a hit of a finger.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select all the way down a column to the first blank row, try this:

Click on top cell.
Press Shift (to select as you move) + Ctrl (to jump) + down arrow (to the bottom).

Similarly for up/down/left/right arrows.

For partial columns, or to get past gaps, use Shift + up/down and/or page up/page down
You can do these in combination as long as you don't let go of Shift, eg: Shift + Page down then up three rows and across two to the right, then let go of Shift.

Answer (score 0):

what I found is it depends on the mouse. I am able to do it with a logitech M100 but not a M535. I don’t know why.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1101593)